# Django rest framework including "X-CSRFTOKEN" header, receiving "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect"

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, react-native-ios

I am currenty creating a react native ios application where I am interacting with a django rest framework backend. I authenticate with the backend and store the *csrftoken*, *sessionid*, and *messages* cookies in asyncStorage.

The backend view I have is

```
class ItemList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

A GET request example is:

```
axios({
    url:'https://myapi.com/api/items/',
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
     Cookie: mycookies,
}),...
```

A POST request example is:

```
axios({
    url:'https://myapi.com/api/items/',
    method: "POST",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
     Cookie: mycookies,
     'X-CSRFTOKEN': cookies.csrftoken.value
}),...
```

*NOTE: mycookies is the full string of cookies while cookies is the javascript object. This is not a typo.*

Shortly after I authenticate, both the GET and POST requests work. I can retrieve and create items from the api. However, If I close out of the Ios application and reopen the POST request stops working. The GET request will return a 200 response but the POST request returns a 403 authentication error with the message "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect".

When I send the POST request I am certain the csrftoken, sessionid, and messages cookies are still correct, and I've checked that the X-CSRFTOKEN header matches the csrftoken cookie. I am thinking the csrftoken is changing for the POST requests and the XCSRF-TOKEN I am sending is incorrect. However if this was the case, the GET requests would not be working either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I too have this issue, and have been unable to resolve it. Have you made any progress on this?